# In Crashing, is that really Sarah Silverman's house?

Tags: production, film-location, crashing

Many elements of HBO's *Crashing* are authentic:

- Artie Lange is a New York comedian and we see him making his own jokes during stand up.
- Artie Lange has a podcast, and would talk with another New York comedian like Sarah Silverman on his podcast.
- Rachel Ray appeared on the actual set of her actual show, with her actual husband.

I hope this question isn't too naïve, but in the episode where Pete crashes at Sarah Silverman's home, is that Sarah's actual home? If not, is it a set designed to look like her home?